# Configure proxy with Publish-AzureWebsiteProject

Tags: powershell, azure, proxy

I am using: Publish-AzureWebsiteProject to publish a service to azure.

The deployment is very unreliable due to the company proxy.

How do I have to configure the Publish-AzureWebsiteProject to accept proxy url?

In best case someone has experience with cntlm proxy service which I use!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i know there is no possibility to do that in the Powershell. But, as Publish-AzureWebSiteProject uses Web Deploy, you may want to use

```
<system.net>
    <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true" />
</system.net>
```

Comment: But where should  I define that xml using Publish-AzureWebSiteProject explicitly?

Comment: See if that [helps](http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/ConfigureDotNETApp)

Comment: Powershell is not a .net project having a app.config where I can define that proxy.

Comment: Powershell commandlet uses web deploy - you deploy the Azure Web Site project, yes? Define that in the Web Site configuration

Comment: Ok thanks found something: <configuration>
  <system.net>
    <defaultProxy>
      <proxy
              proxyaddress="localhost:3128"    
      />
    </defaultProxy>
  </system.net>
</configuration>